# ホストOSWindows Server 2012 R2のゲストOSとしてWindows Server 2019はサポートされていますか？

Tags: windows-server

タイトルの件、Windows Server 2016は、Windows Server 2012 R2のゲストOSとしてサポートされている認識ですが、Windows Server 2019はサポートされていますでしょうか？

ご存知の方がおりましたらおしえてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supported Windows Guest Operating Systems for Hyper-V in Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn792027(v=ws.11)

上記のリストには記載がありません。
Windows Server 2012 R2で動くHyper-V で、Windows Server 2019をゲストとして動作させることはサポートされないようです。

また、下記の John Marlin [MSFT] のコメントでは、前後1個のバージョンをサポートするとのことです。
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/3e96fc18-31d9-40c5-952f-f08900b34086/server-2019-vms-on-server-2016-hyperv-hosts?forum=winserverhyperv

Comment: 申し訳ありません。ゲストOSとホストOSを書き間違えました。まったく逆の質問となります。ホストOSWindows Server2012 R2に対してゲストOSWindows Server2019がサポートされるかになります。

Comment: 回答を書き換えました.